# Cypress Cucumber BDD steps are not linking with the step definitions on rider IDE

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cucumber, cypress, integration-testing

I'm writing tests on Cypress with Cucumber BDD. I'm using Rider as IDE. The problem is when I click on the steps it should go to the step definition of the test, but it doesn't. The tests run just fine but this situation makes writing BDD tests much harder. When I click any step, I want to go to the relevant step definition. How can I fix this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XuUR.png)

The things I have done so far are these:

1. I have checked the step definitions path in the package.json folder.

"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
"nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
"stepDefinitions": "cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*.js"
}
}

2. I have tried to reinstall the plugins below.

Cucumber.js ->Jetbrains
Gherkin ->Jetbrains

The current versions of the tools I use:
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^18.0.1",
"@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.2.0",
"cucumber": "^6.0.7",
"cypress": "^12.17.2",